# How to integrate biometrics to Cognito an IOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, biometrics

How can integrate IOS biometrics into AWS Cognito?

I trying to use Soto SDK to connect to AWS Cognito. It doesn't work to combine IOS biometrics with AWS Cognito. Do you have any solution to make it work? login by biometrics from an ios device connects to Cognito.

Comment: You can't login with iOS biometrics alone. Once the user has logged in with username and password you can store their tokens in the keychain and protect it via biometrics so that they need to authenticate to access the tokens.